# Emacs -- how to consolidate :lighter(s) for minor modes

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to consolidate `:lighters` on the mode-line when a certain combination of active minor modes exists?  If so, then how please?

Example:

- Minor mode number one has a :lighter of `" -"`
- Minor mode number two has a :lighter of `" +"`

If both minor modes are active in the buffer, then consolidate lighters:   `" ±"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can dynamically alter the lighter value for any minor MODE by modifying `minor-mode-alist`:

```el
(setcar (cdr (assq 'MODE minor-mode-alist)) VALUE)
```

When either of your modes is activated or deactivated, check the status of the other, and set the lighter text accordingly. When both are active you can make one an empty string, and the other your 'combined' lighter.

Or, better, take advantage of the fact that any mode-line construct is valid, and make it automatic. Using [delight.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelightedModes) as a wrapper for the above, and assuming both modes are defined by `mylibrary.el` you might say:

```el
(delight '((mode+ (mode- " ±" " +") "mylibrary")
           (mode- (mode+ "" " -") "mylibrary")))
```

That's not perfect -- if you want the associated pop-up menus to also combine the details of both modes, there's rather more to do; but I would recommend that you don't worry about that if you don't need to. The *appearance* of the mode line is the low-hanging fruit here.

Comment: What a delightful little library that is!!!  Thank you very much for the link and also for the example of how to use it -- greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: I second the usefulness of delight.el. But I would draw attention to the note in the `Commentary` that mentions that some modes dynamically update the lighter. In such cases you will need to consult the source code if you want to modify the lighter text without losing functionality. Examples: [Isearch+](http://www.emacswiki.org/IsearchPlus) (shows case sensitivity and wraparound) and [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) (shows current completion behavior).

Comment: Library [`WideN`](http://www.emacswiki.org/MultipleNarrowings) is another one that dynamically changes the lighter (text and keymap/help).